# Strategy for assigning a unique price for all customers based on a condition in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am working on a web store application where each customer is assigned a unique markup value for all products so that each customer has his/her own custom pricing. Two attributes in my Products collection are invoicePrice and memberPrice. memberPrice = invoicePrice x markup value.

Is there an efficient way for me to give each customer a custom memberPrice without having to create a custom Products collection for each customer that contains their custom memberPrice?

Note 1 - I am using a datatables package to present the product list to the customer and it doesn't allow me to modify the data (such as the memberPrice calculation) once the data is sent to the datatable.

Note 2 - I could make the memberPrice calculation and modification on the client side using javascript, but that would expose the invoicePrice and custom markup to the client, which is not secure.

Note 3 - I am building the app using Meteor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the easiest way would be to dynamically compute the price when it's presented but as you say your datatables package won't let you do that.

One alternative is to make a client-side only collection that gets filled with the products and pricing for that user and then render that with your datatables package. A clever customer would however be able to modify his/her pricing from the console. You'd have to validate the price used at checkout on the server.

To create a client-side only collection:

```
myLocalCollection = new Collection(null);
```